# XCode 5 strange behavior - old layouts

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode

This problem has been killing me for many months now since I upgraded from XCode 4.6 to 5.0.

This is the problem.

- I created a brand new app/project in XCode 5.
- I made deployment target to be iOS 6.0.
- I created a navigation bar in storyboard
- I deployed the app on my actual iphone device that is running iOS 7
- I see the "old" navigation bar layout screen (see screenshot)
- I close the project, go to my DerivedData dir and clean everything there.
- Open my project again and rebuild and low and behold I see new iOS 7 layout.
- Note: in iOS 7 simulator it show everything perfectly every single time.

this has been happening to me with every single project that I have created. I have to do this clean of dir, sometime multiple times a day otherwise it keeps reverting back to old iOS look and feel on actual device even though the device is running iOS 7.

The worst part is that I had upgraded one of my app to iOS 7, sent it over to AppStore, and when I downloaded that binary from appstore it shows me "old" look and feel of iOS 6. How did that happen?

What am I doing wrong and how I can I force it to use new iOS 7 layout every time on my device?

NOTE: this is the same app running on the same iPhone iOS 7 device.

[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: Can you interact with the iOS 6 looking elements? It seems to me that it may just be a launch image that has the iOS 6 style.

Comment: I can interact with elements. What launch image? My app has no launch images

Comment: In Xcode 5, your launch images are generated automatically. Click on your project > target > general, and scroll down a bit and you'll see what it's using for your launch images.  But if you can interact with the iOS 6 style elements, then it's not that you just have an image that looks like iOS 6.

Answer (score -1):

Maybe, do you have two sdks in xcode?
It's looks like you build app with old sdk6.

I supported old app for ios6 and had in xcode two sdks - sdk7 and sdk6. When i build with sdk6 - i saw old style elements in iPhone with ios7.

Comment: check screen shot. I am using the latest one and this doesn't answer why it would show old/new with just clearing up of dervieddata dir

Comment: Have another ui-elements ios6-style? If yes - it mean, you build app with ios6 sdk - check all target settings (what different debug settings from release?). If all target ok - ...maybe reinstalling x-code or explicit removing sdk6 from x-code?